# use sonatype nexus for macports

Tags: macports, sonatype

Is there a way to setup Sonatype Nexus with macports proxy. I tried it but i could not find rsync being supported by nexus.

/opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf can take http protocol, but does not work in my case

i configure proxy in macports.conf

proxy_http              proxy.local.dev:80
proxy_https             proxy.local.dev:80

but i get 403 forbidden error, when i try to install a package

```
$sudo port install ack
```

error:

```
0DEBUG: Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported. Your best bet at current time would be to try and use a raw repository as a proxy, but you might have already tried that.

The other more fun but time consuming alternative is to create your own format! One of our community members did this with APT, you can check out their work here: https://github.com/mpoindexter/nexus-repository-apt